# python - lists are being read in from csv as strings

Tags: python, csv, pandas, read-write

I have a dictionary that uses an strings(edit) as keys and stores lists of lists as values.

```
dict = {key1: [[data1],[data2],[data3]], key2: [[data4],[data5]],...etc}
```

EDIT: where the data variables are rows containing different data types from a converted pandas DataFrame

Ex.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['City'] = ['New York','Austin','New Orleans','New Orleans']
df['State'] = ['NY','TX','LA','LA']
df['Latitude'] = [29.12,23.53,34.53,34.53]
df['Time'] = [1.46420e+09,1.47340e+09,1.487820e+09,1.497820e+09]

City         State    Latitude   Time
New York     NY       29.12      1.46420e+09
Austin       TX       23.53      1.47340e+09
New Orleans  LA       34.53      1.487820e+09
New Orleans  LA       34.53      1.497820e+09

dict = {}
cities = df['City'].unique()
for c in cities:
    temp = df[df['City'] == c]
    dict[c] = temp.as_matrix().tolist()

#which outputs this for a given key
dict['New Orleans'] = [['New Orleans' 'LA' 34.53  1.487820e+09],
    ['New Orleans' 'LA' 34.53  1.497820e+09]]
```

I am storing it as a csv using the following:

```
filename = 'storage.csv'
with open(filename,'w') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key in dict.keys():
        w.writerow((key,dict[key]))
```

I then read the file back into a dictionary using the following:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filename, 'r'))
dict = {}
for key,val in reader:
    dict[key] = val
```

val comes in looking perfect, except it is now a string. for example, key1 looks like this:

```
dict[key1] = "[[data1],[data2],[data3]]"
```

How can I read the values in as lists, or remove the quotes from the read-in version of val?

Comment: What are the variables `data1`, `data2`, etc? Show [minimal complete code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: CSV doesn't know what a python list is. Why don't you use json ?

Comment: Assuming `val` is a string representing a list of strings then `d[key] = ast.literal_eval(val)`.  Also, don't name your dictionary `dict`.

Comment: edited for more detail

Comment: Since you are using a `pandas.DataFrame` don't use the `csv` module.  Use panda's builtin [io tools](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for both reading and writing.

Comment: I've had success using the pandas tools when I want to only store a single DataFrame, but wasn't able to find anything for storing them as dictionary values like I wanted to in this case. Do you know of a way to do that?

Comment: I've added the `pandas` tag, so maybe the `pandas` people will be able to give a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** Since you are using a `pandas.DataFrame` don't use the `csv` module or `json` module.  Instead, use [`pandas.io`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) for both reading and writing.

---

**Original Answer:**

Short answer: use `json`.

CSV is fine for saving tables of strings.  Anything further than that and you need to manually convert the strings back into Python objects.

If your data has just lists, dictionaries and basic literals like strings and numbers `json` would be the right tool for this job.

Given:

```
example = {'x': [1, 2], 'y': [3, 4]}
```

Save to file:

```
with open('f.txt','w') as f:
    json.dump(example, f)
```

Load from file:

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    reloaded_example = json.load(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

your code must be like :

```
import csv
import ast
#dict = {1: [[1],[2],[3]], 2: [[4],[5]]}
reader = csv.reader(open("storage.csv", 'r'))
dict = {}
for key,val in reader:
    dict[int(key)] = ast.literal_eval(val)
print dict
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a useful function `literal_eval`

Comment: This is quite useful. I edited my question to show the varying data types of my lists so it didn't end up working in this case, but I will remember for the future.